# Why my code JavaScript code is recalling itself

Tags: javascript, html, api

I am trying to create a quote generator. Everything is almost ok but sometimes the code is recalling itself automatically.

In JavaScript, I have used `try and catch` for the situation if it fails to load a quote. I opened the chrome debugger tool and see there, for the error case it is recalling the function multiple times. But I don't want that.

**The code is recalling the function also after a successful quote load.**

My code:

```js
const quoteEl = document.getElementById("quote");
const authorEl = document.getElementById("author");
const twitterEl = document.getElementById("twitter");
const newQuoteEl = document.getElementById("new-quote");
const quoteIconEl = document.getElementById("quote-icon");

async function getQuote() {
    const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const apiUrl = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=json";
    try {
        const response = await fetch(proxyUrl + apiUrl);
        const data = await response.json();

        quoteEl.innerText = data.quoteText;

        if (data.quoteAuthor === "") {
            authorEl.innerText = "Unknown";
        } else {
            authorEl.innerText = data.quoteAuthor;
        }

        if (data.quoteText.length >= 100) {
            quoteIconEl.classList.add("quote-icon-sm");
            quoteEl.classList.add("quote-text-sm");
            authorEl.classList.add("quote-author-sm");
        } else {
            oteIconEl.classList.remove("quote-icon-sm");
            quoteEl.classList.remove("quote-text-sm");
            authorEl.classList.remove("quote-author-sm");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        getQuote()
        console.log("Oops! No quote found.\nError -", error);
    }
}

getQuote();

function postOnTwitter() {
    const twitterUrl = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${quoteEl.innerText} - ${authorEl.innerText}`;
    window.open(twitterUrl, "_blank");
}

twitterEl.addEventListener("click", postOnTwitter);
newQuoteEl.addEventListener("click", getQuote);
```

```css
* {
    /* margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box; */
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 304 304' width='304' height='304'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23000000' fill-opacity='0.2' d='M44.1 224a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-2h44.1zm160 48a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H82v-2h122.1zm57.8-46a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H304v2h-42.1zm0 16a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H304v2h-42.1zm6.2-114a5 5 0 1 1 0 2h-86.2a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h86.2zm-256-48a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-2h12.1zm185.8 34a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h86.2a5 5 0 1 1 0 2h-86.2zM258 12.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V0h2v12.1zm-64 208a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-54.2a5 5 0 1 1 2 0v54.2zm48-198.2V80h62v2h-64V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm16 16V64h46v2h-48V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-128 96V208h16v12.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V210h-16v-76.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-5.9-21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H114v48H85.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H112v-48h12.1zm-6.2 130a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H176v-74.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V242h-60.1zm-16-64a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H114v48h10.1a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H112v-48h-10.1zM66 284.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V274H50v30h-2v-32h18v12.1zM236.1 176a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H226v94h48v32h-2v-30h-48v-98h12.1zm25.8-30a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H274v44.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V146h-10.1zm-64 96a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H208v-80h16v-14h-42.1a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H226v18h-16v80h-12.1zm86.2-210a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H272V0h2v32h10.1zM98 101.9V146H53.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H96v-42.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM53.9 34a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80V0h2v34H53.9zm60.1 3.9V66H82v64H69.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80V64h32V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM101.9 82a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H128V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V82h-28.1zm16-64a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H146v44.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V18h-26.1zm102.2 270a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H98v14h-2v-16h124.1zM242 149.9V160h16v34h-16v62h48v48h-2v-46h-48v-66h16v-30h-16v-12.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM53.9 18a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H64V2H48V0h18v18H53.9zm112 32a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H192V0h50v2h-48v48h-28.1zm-48-48a5 5 0 0 1-9.8-2h2.07a3 3 0 1 0 5.66 0H178v34h-18V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V32h14V2h-58.1zm0 96a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H137l32-32h39V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V66h-40.17l-32 32H117.9zm28.1 90.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-76.51L175.59 80H224V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V82h-49.59L146 112.41v75.69zm16 32a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-99.51L184.59 96H300.1a5 5 0 0 1 3.9-3.9v2.07a3 3 0 0 0 0 5.66v2.07a5 5 0 0 1-3.9-3.9H185.41L162 121.41v98.69zm-144-64a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-3.51l48-48V48h32V0h2v50H66v55.41l-48 48v2.69zM50 53.9v43.51l-48 48V208h26.1a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-65.41l48-48V53.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-16 16V89.41l-34 34v-2.82l32-32V69.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM12.1 32a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H9.41L0 43.41V40.6L8.59 32h3.51zm265.8 18a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h18.69l7.41-7.41v2.82L297.41 50H277.9zm-16 160a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H288v-71.41l16-16v2.82l-14 14V210h-28.1zm-208 32a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H64v-22.59L40.59 194H21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H41.41L66 216.59V242H53.9zm150.2 14a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H96v-56.6L56.6 162H37.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h19.5L98 200.6V256h106.1zm-150.2 2a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80v-46.59L48.59 178H21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H49.41L82 208.59V258H53.9zM34 39.8v1.61L9.41 66H0v-2h8.59L32 40.59V0h2v39.8zM2 300.1a5 5 0 0 1 3.9 3.9H3.83A3 3 0 0 0 0 302.17V256h18v48h-2v-46H2v42.1zM34 241v63h-2v-62H0v-2h34v1zM17 18H0v-2h16V0h2v18h-1zm273-2h14v2h-16V0h2v16zm-32 273v15h-2v-14h-14v14h-2v-16h18v1zM0 92.1A5.02 5.02 0 0 1 6 97a5 5 0 0 1-6 4.9v-2.07a3 3 0 1 0 0-5.66V92.1zM80 272h2v32h-2v-32zm37.9 32h-2.07a3 3 0 0 0-5.66 0h-2.07a5 5 0 0 1 9.8 0zM5.9 0A5.02 5.02 0 0 1 0 5.9V3.83A3 3 0 0 0 3.83 0H5.9zm294.2 0h2.07A3 3 0 0 0 304 3.83V5.9a5 5 0 0 1-3.9-5.9zm3.9 300.1v2.07a3 3 0 0 0-1.83 1.83h-2.07a5 5 0 0 1 3.9-3.9zM97 100a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-48 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 96a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-144a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-96 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm96 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-32 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM49 36a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-32 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM33 68a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 240a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm80-176a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm112 176a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM17 180a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM17 84a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

#container {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.quote-container {
    max-width: 968px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.quote-text {
    font-size: 2.75rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#quote-icon {
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.quote-author {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Dynamic Classes */
.quote-icon-sm {
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.quote-text-sm {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.quote-author-sm {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media (max-width: 375px) {
    .quote-text {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .quote-author {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    #quote-icon {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quote Generator</title>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/djz3p8sux/image/upload/v1629822917/image/general-purpose-favicon-dabananda-mitra_zuuv1x.png">
    <!-- FontAwesome Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Bootstrap Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="container">
            <div class="quote-container p-3" id="quote-container">
                <div class="quote-text" id="quote-text">
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left" id="quote-icon"></i>
                    <span class="quote" id="quote"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="quote-author mt-2 mb-4">-
                    <span id="author"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="twitter">
                        <i class="bi bi-twitter"></i> tweet
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="new-quote">
                        New Quote
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: why you add it into a catch there is a condition it always break and it will go in catch its like an infinite loop

Comment: try to check object shouldn't be empty

Comment: You're supposed to add a [mcve] that only has the relevant stuff and not just dump all your script/markup on us -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the code, you are calling `getQuote()`.

Then, if you have an error, it will also call `getQuote()` method. But, such as you will always have an issue, it will always loop.

I suggest you to print error, and try to prevent/fix it, or just remove the `getQuote()` in the error clause.

Finally, you can just print the error and AFTER call the get quote method, to always show error and then run again the method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code keeps calling itself, coz the fetch call returns with a failure response.

> "Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with"

And you are trying to parse it using `response.json()`

Which forces your code to go to the catch block where you again call the getQuote() method. A good practice would be to at least limit the number of retries so that your application doesn't freeze.